# I'm doing some basic logic function + decimal rounding stuff, and this doesn't seem to work...why?

Tags: python, variables, logic, decimal

```
temperature=int(input("What temperature are you?"))

if temperature>=37 and temperature<50:
    print("your temperature is healthy, as it is" , "%.2f" %temperature)

else:
    print("You said your temperature was" , "%.2f" %temperature , "You are unhealthy")
```

#why is this not working??? when I input the temperature at a whole number, it's fine. When I type in 37.888888, the terminal spits out error.

I tried adjusting it and it didn't work

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback of the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
temperature=int(input("What temperature are you?"))
```

When you pass a string to `int()`, it must be a whole number.  Decimals like 37.8 aren't allowed.

I think you could just use `float()` instead of `int()`.